# Adjacency matrix using igraph package

Tags: r, graph, igraph, adjacency-matrix

I use `igraph` package in `R` for Social Network Analysis. I decide to work with `Movielens Dataset (Movies Section)`, I also loaded the `igraph Library`, when I wanted to work with adjacency matrix.

The dataset loaded successfully, and these r my codes.

```
ff = read.csv("D:/TMU/DataSet/MovieLens/movies.csv", header = TRUE)
ff
mtr = as.matrix(ff)
gr = graph.adjacency(mtr, mode = "undirected", weighted = NULL, diag = FALSE)
```

I faced with this error :

> Error in graph.adjacency.dense(adjmatrix, mode = mode, weighted = weighted,  :
>         At structure_generators.c:274 : Non-square matrix, Non-square matrix
>       In addition: Warning message:
>       In mde(x) : NAs introduced by coercion

is there a problem with dataset or what ?

Comment: An adjacency matrix should be square (same number of columns as rows). Does your data have this - `dim(ff)`. Can you share the data?

Comment: @user20650 , my result of dim(ff) is [1] 9125    2 . number of columns are not as same as rows

Comment: okay, thanks: so is the data from "http://files.grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/ml-latest-small.zip"

Answer (score 0):

Okay, using the small dataset from https://grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/ which has dimension 9125x3

Download the data (you may need to tweak the `mode` in the `download.file` if you are using windows)

```
pth <- "http://files.grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/ml-latest-small.zip"
download.file(pth, destfile=temp<-tempfile())
#unzip(temp, list=TRUE) # see what files?
unzip(temp, exdir=td<-tempdir()) 

# read movies dataset
movies <- read.csv(file.path(td, "ml-latest-small/movies.csv"), 
                   header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Load some libraries

```
library(tm) # to form the binary matrix: best to keep things sparse
library(slam) # for the crossproduct of the simple_triplet_matrix returned by tm::DocumentTermMatrix
library(igraph)
```

Form binary matrix for movies by genres (had to use MrFlick's [suggestion of VCorpus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43441713/using-documenttermmatrix-on-a-vector-of-first-and-last-names) otherwise "(no genres listed)" and "film-noir" were split into the individual words

```
# split the genres string and create binary matrix for presence of genre
corp <- VCorpus(VectorSource(movies$genres))
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(corp, 
                          control = list(tokenize = function(x) 
                            unlist(strsplit(as.character(x), "\\|"))))
```

Create adjacency matrix

```
# this looks for agreement across the genres
# you could use tcrossprod for similarities on the films
adj <- crossprod_simple_triplet_matrix(dtm)
```

Create graph

```
g <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(adj, mode="undirected", weighted=TRUE)
```